# Afwall+ Android Firewall for multiuser

Tags: internet, multi-user, firewall, 8.1-oreo

Hi guys After rooting my andoid phone to prevent excessive data usage by Android  system and installed AFWall+ that is based on iptables.
U have two users on device both account are handled by me by this It is easier to separte work and home profile separetly
AFWall works as supposed in owner mode but on switching   user Apps are not able to work (browsing,load pics do chats all stuff related to internet) but on again switching to owner mode I am able to browse internet

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Looks like they're asking why this AFWall+ app doesn't work when they switch users on the device, which probably has something to do with how users are handled on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences/Experimental in Afwall+ (I am currently using v3.1.0), and enable Multi-user support!

Source: [Android Island work profile apps and AFWall](https://nyllep.wordpress.com/2017/05/01/android-island-work-profile-apps-and-afwall/)

Answer (score 0):

2018-12-09 Same problem on Samsung Galaxy tablet, Android 8.0.1, Afwall+ 3.0.1, rooted with TWRP 1.19, Magisk 17.3. I'm new to Afwall+. Did what I thought is basic application on/off settings. Afwall+ performs as expected for owner account, but seems to completely block internet for other users. Disable Afwall+ and internet works for all users.
Was unable to find Afwall log entries that appear relevant.

Selecting "(Any app) - Same as selecting all apps" allows internet access for all users. This is different from selecting all of the apps individually, not including (Any app), which does not allow internet access for other users.

Hope to contribute more as I learn how rules are implemented. Thanks.